# Multiple graphs output using `{tikzDevice}` to a single tex file in R

Tags: r, latex, tikzdevice

I want to output graphs to a single tex file using `{tikzDevice}`, I wrote following loop trying to make it happen:

```
library{tikzDevice}

graphList <- list(...) # ... are the graphs I have made using ggplot2

for (i in 1:length(graphList)) {

    cat("\\begin{figure}\n", file = "GraphList.tex", append=TRUE)
    sink("GraphList.tex", append=TRUE)

    tikz(console = TRUE)
    graphList[[i]]
    dev.off()

    sink()

    cat(paste0("\\caption{", names(graphList)[[i]],"}",sep=" "), 
    file = "GraphList.tex", append=TRUE)
    cat("\\end{figure}\n", file = "GraphList.tex", append=TRUE)
 }
```

Sometimes it works but sometimes does not by just writing what I put in the `cat` part into `tex` file without graphs.

I am pretty newbie to this, could anyone help me out of here? Many Thanks!

Updated:

The following code works (Suppose I only have 2 graphs in list for example):

```
   sink("Output/graph/GraphList.tex", append=TRUE)

   tikz(console = TRUE)
   cat("\\begin{figure}\n")
   graphList[[1]]
   cat(paste0("\\caption{", names(graphList)[[1]],"}",sep=" "))
   cat("\n\\end{figure}\n")

   cat("\n\\begin{figure}\n")
   graphList[[2]]
   cat(paste0("\\caption{", names(graphList)[[2]],"}",sep=" "))
   cat("\n\\end{figure}\n")

   sink()
```

So my wild guess is that `R` does not write loop part into a file, is that correct?

Comment: If the code I have written makes no sense to you, you can also share your thoughts how to output multiple graphs into a single `tex` file, it will be much appreciated!